# Shared files are not deleted from Dropbox accounts of my friends

Tags: dropbox

I wanted to delete my files from Dropbox account. What is more I wanted this files to be deleted from acounts of my friends, becase I shared this files with my friends.

I completely deleted my Dropbox account. But later I realized that the files I shared to my friends was not deleted.

How do I force these files to be deleted from their accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no way to delete these files from your friends' Dropbox accounts by hindsight.

The only way to delete those files is when you unshare shared folders, you're asked if you want to keep shared files on others Dropbox accounts.

Comment: And, even so, if they've copied or moved the files somewhere else you'll not be able to delete them.